# Blank .net file generating "Illegal characters in path" error

Tags: .net, debugging, iis

I have a completely blank ".aspx" file residing on an IIS6 web server.  The server has .net 3.5 installed.

When executed, this file generates an "Illegal characters in path" error.  A full stack trace of this error is [available here](http://jsbin.com/ugowe).

The problem can be temporarily cured by IISReset.  However, once any site on this server starts exhibiting this problem, every hit to every .aspx page on that site will cause the same issue (including my completely blank example file).

What might be causing this, and how do I fix it?

**Edit**:  I've added a bounty in the hopes of getting some more help with this before we open a support case with Microsoft.  I have seen the [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922780) and [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2007/03/18/system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path.aspx) that Adam Hughes pointed out, but that information by itself doesn't offer a complete solution. The blog is written for people who have knowledge and skill that I lack, but apparently I need to pick up.  I need help understanding some of the connections and reasoning going on here.

I am specifically looking for help with any of these questions, whichever ones will lead me to a functioning system:

1. The knowledge base article's workaround has me selecting a CGI program executable in step six.  What am I supposed to select here?  Is the debugging process described in the blog supposed to lead me to discovering which program to choose for this?
2. The blog post talks about a means of debugging this, but it assumes I have knowledge that I don't have (yet).  Although I have deduced that I will need [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/286350), I've never used this tool, or otherwise needed to inspect a memory dump before.  I am not sure what to do when the author says this:

   > With time pressing on a not a lot to
   >   lose I went for the live debug
   >   approach. In this way, thanks to the
   >   problem being readily reproducible at
   >   this time, I soon got the needed
   >   memory dump.

   How do I use ADPlus (or any other tool) to generate the memory dump, and how do I make sure the memory dump contains the information I need to debug this?  Will "adplus -crash -iis" do what I want?
3. The issue is happening on a production server.  While I can reboot this server if I really have to, I need to avoid being disruptive if possible. Is it a safe and reasonable idea to generate a memory dump on a live server?  Will the server's other functions be affected by this, and if so, what should I look out for?
4. Does it sound like I am on the right track?  What other avenues should I be looking at to solve this?

**Edit:** Vinay, here is the information you requested involving ISAPI Filters and wildcard mappings:

[image: ISAPI Filters]
<sub>(source: [photobooks.com](http://chris.photobooks.com/Other/forumPosts/ISAPI_Filters.png))</sub>

[image: Wildcard Mappings]
<sub>(source: [photobooks.com](http://chris.photobooks.com/Other/forumPosts/Wildcards.png))</sub>

The full path for the file associated with .aspx files is `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`.

We have a mirror of this server on our local network. I was able to use that to search through all instances of web.config, and I did not find anything unusual.  In fact, it looks like we don't ever use this section of web.config, as all of the entries were identical to this:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="..." />
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="..."/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="..." />
</httpHandlers>
```

Looking at this, it appears that I should be suspicious of [ISAPI_Rewrite3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/), which we are currently using to support "friendly" URLs on some ASP Classic sites.  Is this your diagnosis as well?  Am I right in thinking that "fixing" this problem will mean replacing ISAPI_Rewrite3?

**Edit:**  I have removed the ASP.NET entry from the ISAPI filter list.  The full path for this was `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll`.  There are no obvious ill-effects from having removed this.  MSDN [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx#aspnet_http_runtime_topic2) that it is used to help maintain a cookieless session state, which is not vital for this server anyway.

It has been several hours now and the problem has not recurred since removing the ASP.NET filter.  Unfortunately, I do not have a means to reproduce the problem, other than waiting for it to happen again.  I'm going to let it sit until tomorrow evening.  If the problem recurs, I will remove the ISAPI_Rewrite3 filter as well and try again (thankfully, this filter's functionality is not widely used by our clients).  Either way, I will come back and report my results.

I have checked the <httpModules> section as requested. All such entries across all web.config files on this server are identical to this example:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,
               System.Web.Extensions,
               Version=3.5.0.0,
               Culture=neutral,
               PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Um, remove the "completely blank" aspx file???

Comment: The same error happens on all .net files, but I wanted to rule out possible faulty code as being the issue.  The "completely blank" aspx file is the least amount of code required to reproduce the problem: i.e., none whatsoever.  I guess the problem WOULD go away if I removed all .aspx files, but that is a little too zen for me.

Comment: I updated my answer with more suggestions.

Comment: Let's hope for the best. Did you get a chance to look at any server access logs from just after the last IISReset to the first incidence of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to reach for ADPlus just yet - what he found using ADPlus, you already know - namely that the most likely culprit is something which is changing the current directory.

A key point seems to be that IISReset cures the problem for a time, but the problem comes back after some point, as soon as *something* happens on one of the sites on the server. By "sites" here, I assume you mean ASP.NET application - please confirm if this *isn't* the case.

The act that multiple sites are exhibiting the problem indicates that the problem could well be an ISAPI filter or extension, or an .EXE file which is mapped to a wildcard mapping on one or more specific ASP.NET applications.

So, fire up IIS Manager, and update your question with information on ISAPI filters and wildcard mappings. The ISAPI filter information will be in the "ISAPI Filters" tab on the Properties dialog box for the web site  (under "Web Sites" in the tree view in IIS Manager). The wildcard mappings will be in the "Application Configuration" dialog which you invoke from the "Configuration..." button on the Properties dialog for your specific ASP.NET application.

As well as wildcard mappings, see exactly what mappings are registered against .aspx extensions, and report those in your update.

The problem could also be in  `HttpHandlers` installed in individual ASP.NET web sites - so look in the `<httphandler>` section in `Web.config` to see if a handler is defined with something like

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="..." />
```

This may be on an application which is other than the one you're working with. To see if you can track down which one, check the server logs after an IISReset to see which is the first entry to return a 5xx HTTP status code (indicating an internal server error) and look at the request which triggered it. The application which handled it may be the one to focus on.

All the things I've suggested should be safe to do on a production server :-) I'm not suggesting you actually do an IISReset, just check the logs immediately after the last one you did.

**Update:** I've seen the updated information you posted. It might be ISAPI_Rewrite3 or not; I've certainly used it before without any problems. However, I'm surprised to see the ASP.NET_2.0.xxx in the ISAPI filters list - I don't have it in mine (I'm running Windows Server 2003). So, I would (when time permits - you may have to schedule an outage) temporarily remove those two ISAPI filters from the list (in such a way that you can easily restore them again) and see if that makes a difference. If it seems to have gotten worse, add the ASP.NET filter back in (what's the exact path of that entry?) and leave out ISAPI_Rewrite3, then try again.

The reason I'm surprised to see an ASP.NET DLL in the ISAPI filters list is that it's normally configured using the mappings on a per-application basis (where the applications inherit a default configuration). It normally works as an ISAPI *extension*, not an ISAPI *filter*.

Can you also please check the `<httpmodules>` sections in the same way as for `<httphandlers>`?

It may be necessary to run aspnet_regiis again, which initialises the ASP.NET system for IIS; This is, however *a big step* that could break lots of things. If possible, copy the entire server to a spare machine on a separate test or dev network and do it there. Can you use your local mirror for this kind of testing?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!  I have gathered the requested information and updated my question.

Comment: Thank you again; I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Everything seems good so far.  If it starts recurring again, you've given me some good leads to follow up.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

See [KB 922780](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922780): Error message when a CGI program that is written by using the .NET Framework 2 makes Web service calls: "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path"

and the associated [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2007/03/18/system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path.aspx).  Your code is failing during a call to `GetCurrentDirectory`, just like the one in the blog post.

Comment: The KB article is interesting, but I am stuck on step 6: what CGI program am I supposed to select there?  The blog post sounds similar to my issue, but it goes over my head. How do I produce a memory dump, how do I ensure it contains the information that I need, and is this something I would want to do on a production server?

Answer (score 0):

In `Global.asax` put the following:

```
private static string EnvironmentDir = null; 
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     EnvironmentDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
}

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = EnvironmentDir;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  However, the issue has already been resolved: after removing the ASP.NET entry from the ISAPI filters list as Vinay Sajip suggested, the problem has not recurred in over a month.  I appreciate the assistance, though!